# LSMDS3 accelerometer and gyroscope sensor returns register addresses instead of values on most registers

Tags: spi, imu

I use an [LSM6DS3 IMU sensor](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds3tr-c.pdf) to detect acceleration and turn rates in 3 Dimensions.

I can read the WHOAMI and the measurement value registers. I get correct readings that change in the expected manner when I move the sensor.

Now I wanted to change the configuration. For this I execute a write routine and then read back the value that I've just written. To my surprise the returned value is always the register address. Also, the sensor does not change it's behavior when I write registers, (I tried changing the full scale selection. That should have resulted in different measurement values, but they did not change). It seems like the registers do nothing, and the only ones that actually work are the WHOAMI and the measurement output registers. I checked the whole setup with an oscilloscope multiple times. The SPI is running smooth (and extra slow), all signals are clean. The Clock phase and polarity are correct and in line with the IMUs Datasheet. Also, the values I receive in the SPI buffer are actually the values that are on the MISO line, I checked that too.

Some details: I set the MSBit to 1 for reading and 0 for writing (like the datasheet says). The SPI transfers 2 bytes (also according to the DS). The second received byte is the read register value. I know there are write protected registers called "embedded function registers". The question is not about those.

Anything I forgot to check?

Did I just miss a detail and the other registers have a different reading routine? (The datasheet says nothing about it). Did I buy a Chinese fake chip that just provides the bare minimum? In this case I'd expect more people having the problem, but I can't find anything on the I-Net.
Did I get a damaged chip?